# Android Studio TextToSpeech run issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file-io, text-to-speech

I am basically making a firstaid training app (to help get people prepared for NL (National lifeguard) and Standard first aid).

This is done in a multiple choice form factor, and I have an activity which pulls all the questions, answers, and explanations and stores them in an array. As the user answers each question, it moves onto the next by replacing the text on the buttons and textview of the question, and I have made it so android says the question using TextToSpeech.

My error, is that for some reason on the first question, the string (question) gets given to the TextToSpeech talker, but it does not say it? What is weird is that for the other questions (2,3,4,etc.) it works, just not for the first.

I thought that maybe it was that it didnt have enough time to construct (which some other thread said was the problem when the TextToSpeech lags), so I added a delay to the button that starts the multiple choice activity and it still did not work for the first question, but works for the rest.

Here is my code for the TextToSpeech:

In the onCreate of the class:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_menu);
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.comsci.michelaustin.comscisummative", MODE_PRIVATE);
    moduleNumber = getIntent().getIntExtra("MODULE_ID", 0);

    talker = new TextToSpeech(QuizMenuActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                result = talker.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Talking feature not supported on this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

In the method that sets the textview and buttons to the correct question and answers:

```
 private void displayQuestions(){
    String ques = mQuestionLibraryTest.getQuestion(questionNumber);
    questionLabel.setText(ques);
    talker.speak(ques,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);

    option1.setText(getChoice(questionNumber,0));
    option2.setText(getChoice(questionNumber,1));


    option1.setEnabled(true);
    option2.setEnabled(true);
    option3.setEnabled(true);
    option4.setEnabled(true);

    option1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightblue));
    option2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightblue));
    option3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightblue));
    option4.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightblue));
    //to test specifically for true and false questions and to remove visibility of the last two buttons
    if (testWhetherBlank(2)) {
        option3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        option3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        option3.setText(getChoice(questionNumber,2));
    }

    if (testWhetherBlank(3)) {
        option4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        option4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        option4.setText(getChoice(questionNumber,3));
    }

    //
    //answerArray=(ArrayList<Object>)mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(questionNumber).clone();
    answerArray = (ArrayList<String>) mQuestionLibraryTest.getCorrectAnswer(questionNumber).clone();
    //Collections.copy(mQuestionLibraryTest.getCorrectAnswer(questionNumber), answerArray);

    //explanation=mQuestionLibrary.getExplanation(questionNumber);
    explanation = mQuestionLibraryTest.getExplanation(questionNumber);
    amountCorrect=mQuestionLibraryTest.getAnswerAmount(questionNumber);


    nextArrowButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    writeResume();
}

//allows the UI to test and remove buttons if the options are blank
public boolean testWhetherBlank(int q){
    /*if(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(questionNumber,q).equals("")){
        return true;
    }*/
    if(mQuestionLibraryTest.getChoice(questionNumber,q).equals("")){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Question edited: note that the reason for creating the code (summative, etc) and the code deadline have no relevance to the question itself, to the problem that you're asking about, and this information only serves to distract.

Comment: My bad sorry, Im a noob at this... @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: I understand that your deadline and rationale are important to you, but as long as you understand what matters to us is the code, what the code is supposed to be doing, and the current problem with the code. Good luck!